# After running the server below. I use postman to post body but why wont it work?

Tags: node.js, express

I use postman to post body `{"name" : "test"}` in the server below but why wont it work ?  `res.send` cant send `(course)` back.

The server is running OK, as I can get requests with the same url,

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const courses = [
  { id: 1, name: "course1" },
  { id: 2, name: "course2" },
  { id: 3, name: "course3" }
];

app.get("/api/courses", (req, res) => {
res.send(courses);
});

app.post("api/courses", (req, res) => {
  const course = {
    id: courses.length + 1,
    name: req.body.name
  };
  courses.push(course);
  res.send(course);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read your code and added the following:

- In the definition of your endpoint you had placed `api/courses` and the correct thing would be `/api/courses` with the slash(/) at the beginning.
- The final block starts up the server on port '3000' and prints a log comment to the console.

---

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const courses = [
    { id: 1, name: 'course1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'course2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'course3' }
];

app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
    res.send(courses);
});

app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
    const course = {
        id: courses.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    courses.push(course);
    res.send(course);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```